# diff a gzipped tarball against a directory?

Tags: tar, diff, gzip

Is there a way I can diff a gzipped tarball against an existing directory?

I would like to be able to do it without extracting the data from the tarball.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mount the tarball as a directory, for example with [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/). Then use `diff -r` on the real directory and the point where the tarball is mounted.

```
mountavfs
diff -r ~/.avfs/path/to/foo.tar.gz\# real-directory
```

On GNU/Hurd, the equivalent would be `tarfs`.

Comment: What is the `\#` for?

Comment: @Annan AVFS exposes the contents of an archive as a directory whose name is the name of the archive file with a `#` appended. The backslash is unnecessary in most shells.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that GNU tar has diff built in *(-d)*:

```
$ #Create the archive and a difference:
$ echo one>file1;echo two>file2;tar -czf archive.tgz file*;echo changing>>file1
$ tar -dzf archive.tgz
file1: Size differs
```

If you are working with tar that does not have this try:

```
$ for F in `tar -tzf archive.tgz`;do tar -xzOf archive.tgz $F|diff --brief - $F;done
Files - and file1 differ
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new tool: http://diffoscope.org/

Older tool: http://tardiff.sourceforge.net/